# How do I "spoof" the width of a small iframe so that the contents display as desktop instead of following mobile media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

[Here](http://kaitlynbrown.net/web-ux/amanda-brown/) I'm displaying a website preview inside a small (539px wide) iframe so that it appears to be on the screen of a laptop image. As you can see, the website inside the iframe is detecting that the viewport width is less than 768px and is displaying using mobile media queries. How do I "trick" the iframe into thinking it has a width of 1440px so it will display like a desktop preview?

Answer (score 2):

Open to better answers, but I resolved it by setting the iframe's width to 1440px (and height to 902px) in both the HTML and the CSS, and then used CSS `transform: scale(0.3743);` in conjunction with `transform-origin: top left;`, so technically the iframe *is* 1440px wide but has been scaled down. Will have to see how this stands regarding cross-browser compatibility.